# Installing Hook goes wrong

Tags: c, winapi, hook

I am trying to monitor keyboard messages by installing a hook in the message-handling mechanism by using `SetWindowsHookEx()`. My aim is to print a text in the console when `WM_KEYDOWN` or `WM_KEYUP` is being processed. The problem is that I can't reach the hook procedure in my DLL. I think I'm doing something wrong with the message loop. Any suggestions?

Here is the MSDN of KeyboardProc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644984(v=vs.85)

MSDN of hooks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-hooks

Main:

```
int main()
{
    // KeyboardProc(0, WM_KEYUP, 0); < This works
    fun(); // This is to look if the program still imports the functions from DLL

    printf("Loading library\n"); 
    HMODULE libHandle = LoadLibraryA("TestLibrary");
    if (libHandle == NULL) printf("***ERROR*** loading library\n");
     
    printf("Getting address of hook procedure\n");
    HOOKPROC procAddress = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(libHandle, "KeyboardProc");
    if (procAddress == NULL) printf("***ERROR*** getting address\n");

    printf("Installing hook\n");
    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, procAddress, libHandle, 0);
    if (hook == NULL) printf("***ERROR*** installing hook\n");

    printf("Entering message loop\n");
    while (GetMessage(NULL, NULL, 0, 0));

    printf("Deleting hook\n");
    BOOL returnValue = UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
    if (returnValue == NULL) printf("***ERROR*** unhooking\n");
}
```

DLL:

```
void fun()
{
    printf("Program started\n");
}

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(_In_ int code, _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam) 
{
    printf("Entering KeyboardProc\n");
    if (code < 0) // Do not process
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || WM_KEYUP)
    {
        printf("Pressed\n");
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Try Translate/Dispatch the messages?   You seem to be just dumping them:(

Comment: @MartinJames - this is nothing change, because anyway hook will be called in context of another threads.

Comment: @MartinJames I tried it but doesn't work.

Comment: your dll is loaded to another processes ? it 32 or 64 bit ?

Comment: @RbMm The DLL loads successfully, that's the reason I use the fun() function.

Comment: i ask about **another** processes, not about result of call `LoadLibraryA("TestLibrary");`

Comment: @RbMm No this is the only process that uses this DLL.

Comment: you are not understand question ? your dll 32 or 64 bit ? it fail load to another processes, where key down ? why `WH_KEYBOARD` instead `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` ?

Comment: @RbMm My DLL is 64 bit.

Comment: and `SetWindowsHookEx` is ok, but if you press key inside another 64bit process - your dll even not begin load ? begin, but fail ?

Comment: @RbMm It does load and doesn't fail.

Comment: *It does load* - to some **another** process ?

Comment: @RbMm Thank you it works now, I used WH_KEYBOARD_LL. Why does it work now? Any idea?

Comment: Shouldn't the third parameter of SetWindowsHookEx be a HINSTANCE? I'm not sure if that's the same thing as HMODULE in this horrid type system.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for answering I already fixed it. Should I delete the question?

Comment: If you found an answer to the question you can post it yourself (if none else is going to do so). Answering your own questions is perfectly fine.

Comment: FYI, `if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || WM_KEYUP)` does not do what you think. You need `if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_KEYUP)` instead.